# How to center a table on a new line

Tags: tables, lyx

In the Embedded Objects documentation the table section shows a table in the way that I want.

[image]

However, I can't seem to find an explanation of how that was achieved.

How can I get the following table,

[image]

to be on its own line and centered.

Here's the code for the paragraph that contains the table:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item We need to solve for $x$ in the equation $2x^{3}+9x^{2}-11x-30=0$.
Since $x-2$ is a linear factor of $f(x)$ we can use long division
to find the quadratic factor of $f(x)$.%
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
 &  & $2x^{2}$ & $+13x$ & $+15$\tabularnewline
\cline{2-5} 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{$x-2$} & $2x^{3}$ & $+9x^{2}$ & $-11x$ & $-30$\tabularnewline
 & $-2x^{3}$ & $+4x^{2}$ &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-5} 
 &  & $13x^{2}$ & $-11x$ & $-30$\tabularnewline
 &  & $-13x^{2}$ & $+26x$ & \tabularnewline
\cline{3-5} 
 &  &  & $15x$ & $-30$\tabularnewline
 &  &  & $-15x$ & $+30$\tabularnewline
\cline{4-5} 
 &  &  &  & $0$\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}The next step is to factorise $2x^{2}+13x+15$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
2x^{2}+13x+15 & = & 2x^{2}+10x+3x+15\\
 & = & 2x(x+5)+3(x+5)\\
 & = & (x+5)(2x+3)
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, $(x-2)(x+5)(2x+3)=0$. Therefore, either $x=2$, $x=-5$ or
$x=-\frac{3}{2}$ are the solutions of the equation.
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Could you post the (compilable) code you used?

Comment: @Bernard I appended the code to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the table in a paragraph of it's own within the list, then centre that paragraph.

To do this in Lyx:

1. Press enter before your table. You will get a new item in the list.
2. Increase the indent (`[ALT+SHIFT+RIGHT]`).
3. Return to default text (The icon to the left of the enumerate icon) .
4. Press enter after your table to get another new paragraph within the list.
5. Place the cursor in front of the table and go to Edit > Paragraph Settings. In the dialog, change "Alignment" to "Center" and click "OK".

In LaTeX, the code looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item We need to solve for $x$ in the equation $2x^{3}+9x^{2}-11x-30=0$.
    Since $x-2$ is a linear factor of $f(x)$ we can use long division
    to find the quadratic factor of $f(x)$.

    \begin{center}
      \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
        &  & $2x^{2}$ & $+13x$ & $+15$\tabularnewline
        \cline{2-5} 
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$x-2$} & $2x^{3}$ & $+9x^{2}$ & $-11x$ & $-30$\tabularnewline
        & $-2x^{3}$ & $+4x^{2}$ &  & \tabularnewline
        \cline{2-5} 
        &  & $13x^{2}$ & $-11x$ & $-30$\tabularnewline
        &  & $-13x^{2}$ & $+26x$ & \tabularnewline
        \cline{3-5} 
        &  &  & $15x$ & $-30$\tabularnewline
        &  &  & $-15x$ & $+30$\tabularnewline
        \cline{4-5} 
        &  &  &  & $0$\tabularnewline
      \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

    The next step is to factorise $2x^{2}+13x+15$.
    \begin{eqnarray*}
      2x^{2}+13x+15 & = & 2x^{2}+10x+3x+15\\
      & = & 2x(x+5)+3(x+5)\\
      & = & (x+5)(2x+3)
    \end{eqnarray*}
    Hence, $(x-2)(x+5)(2x+3)=0$. Therefore, either $x=2$, $x=-5$ or
    $x=-\frac{3}{2}$ are the solutions of the equation.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```